# LinkedIn work history time

Tags: php, datetime

The code I have works. I was just curious if there was an easier way to write the function.

Note: It is referenced inside of an object so you may need to change the `$this` variables.

```
public function workTime() {

    $startDate = new DateTime($this->start_date);
    $startPretty = date("F Y", strtotime($this->start_date));
    $endDate = new DateTime($this->end_date);
    $endPretty = date("F Y", strtotime($this->end_date));
    $current = $this->current; // boolean true/false        

    if($current) // currently works at this job
    {
        $endDate = new DateTime(); // current date/time
        $endPretty = 'Present';
    }

    $diff = $endDate->diff($startDate);

    if($diff->y = 0)
    {
        if($diff->m > 1)
        {
            $string = $diff->m . ' months';
        }
        else
        {
            $string = '1 month';
        }
    }
    elseif ($diff->y = 1)
    {
        if($diff->m > 1)
        {
            $string = '1 year ' . $diff->m . ' months';
        }
        else
        {
            $string = '1 year 1 month';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if($diff->m > 1)
        {
            $string = $diff->y . ' years ' . $diff->m . ' months';
        }
        else
        {
            $string = $diff->y . ' years 1 month';
        }
    }       
    $output = $startPretty . ' - ' . $endPretty . ' ( ' . $string . ' )';
    return $output;

}
```

Here is some sample data:

> ```
> $this->start_date = '2013-05-01';
> $this->end_date = '2014-12-01';
> ```

or you can make `$this->end_date = null;` and `$current = true;`

It currently outputs:

> May 2013 - Present ( 1 year 7 months )

which is what it should do. I'm just curious if this could be done cleaner/simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already parse the date string using `DateTime`, then it's better to format using that resulting date object instead of parsing again with `strtotime`, for example:

```
$startDate = new DateTime($this->start_date);
$startPretty = $startDate->format('F Y');
```

If `$current` is true, then there's no need to parse `$this->end_date`.
You can move that to the `else` block instead:

```
if($current) // currently works at this job
{
    $endDate = new DateTime(); // current date/time
    $endPretty = 'Present';
}
else
{
    $endDate = new DateTime($this->end_date);
    $endPretty = $endDate->format('F Y');
}
```

These conditions don't do what you think they do:

> ```
> if($diff->y = 0)
> {
>     // ...
> }
> elseif ($diff->y = 1)
> {
>     // ... 
> }
> ```

The `=` operator *assigns*. This is *not* a check for equality.
The result of an assignment is the assigned value.
So the above statements are actually evaluated like this:

> ```
> if(0)  // always false, $diff->y was set to 0, no matter what it was before
> {
>     // ...
> }
> elseif (1)  // always true, $diff->y was set to 1, no matter what it was before
> {
>     // ...
> }
> ```

That is, first `$diff->y` is set to 0, the expression evaluates to false,
then in the `elseif`, `$diff->y` is set to 1, the expression evaluates to true.
To see the problem, set `start_date` to 2 or more years before `end_date`.
The result will always be 1 year difference instead of 2, 3 or more.

What you really wanted is the *equals* operator `==` like this:

```
if($diff->y == 0)
{
    // ...
}
elseif ($diff->y == 1)
{
    // ... 
}
```

Comment: found the `=` and `==` issue out the hard way. I will give this a look. Thanks!